# How to get the value from a component to a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an component which uses the animation part.I would like to have the return value from the component to a variable.

I have tried to like this

```
const temp = <Counter end={500}/>
```

But i am getting the response as [object, object]

```
const temp = <Counter end={needleAngle}/>;
```

Counter Component:

```
export default class Counter extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    start: PropTypes.number,
    end: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    digits: PropTypes.number,
    time: PropTypes.number,
    easing: PropTypes.string,
    onComplete: PropTypes.func,
    style: PropTypes.any,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    start: 0,
    digits: 0,
    time: 1000,
    easing: 'linear',
  };

  state = { value: this.props.start };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.startTime = Date.now();
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }

  animate() {
    const { onComplete } = this.props;

    if (this.stop) {
      if (onComplete) onComplete();
      return;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    this.draw();
  }

  draw() {
    const { time, start, end, easing } = this.props;

    const now = Date.now();
    if (now - this.startTime >= time) this.stop = true;
    const percentage = Math.min((now - this.startTime) / time, 1);
    const easeVal = eases[easing](percentage);
    const value = start + (end - start) * easeVal;

    this.setState({ value });
  }

  render() {
    const { digits } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      // <Text style={style}>{value.toFixed(digits)}</Text>
      value.toFixed(digits)
    );
  }
}
```

I am accesesing this component as mentioned above.

Comment: try `const temp = Counter({end=500})`, but why are you trying something like this, makes no sense

Comment: @VaibhavVishal tried it but getting the value as undefined

Comment: please provide your complete code of components and also clearly state what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to access the value `end`?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I have added the code can you pls check it

Comment: If your are just returning a number from your component make it a function instead. Components are supposed to return some jsx which can be rendered.

Comment: If you don't require to render anything from your `Counter` component and only require to return a value then make a pure function with `export default` or `export` and return your value from there. But in this case you can not use PropTypes and Component lifecycle methods so you need to change your implementation as well. If you want to use only the component then callBack could be a solution.

Comment: Here is one reference in which they are using callBack:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147874/react-native-parent-child-communication-and-return-values/41148983

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get animation value or any value from your custom animation component in your case `Counter` component then you can pass an arrow function as callback and can receive the value like mentioned below:

`const temp = <Counter end={500} callBack={(value) => console.log(value)}/>`

and within your `Counter` component you can call the callback from any where in the component like this:

`this.props.callBack(value);`